# Error : Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::StudentInfo does not exist. (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to make join tables with Eloquent. I want to join 3 tables. But it shows me error. What's my mistake, if anyone notice it will be helpful for me. Here is tables.... 
In 1st table **Applications(id,u_id,program_name)** 2nd table **StudentInfos(id,u_id,.....)** 3rd table **users(id,.....)**

**in Application model**

```
public function StudentInfo()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\StudentInfo', 'u_id', 'u_id');

}
```

**in StudentInfo model**

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\user', 'u_id', 'id');

}
```

**From controller**

```
 public function view_application($id)
  {
    $vu_data = Application::where('id', $id)->get();
    $vu_data2 = $vu_data->StudentInfo()->get();
    return $vu_data2;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When  you do `get()`, it returns a collection. You can do  :

```
$vu_data = Application::findOrFail($id);
$student = $vu_data->StudentInfo;
$user = $student->User;
```

Comment: thanks , if i want to join users as well then what should be?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it require **return $this->belongsTo(Application::class);**?

Comment: Yes you should have belongs to in User Model

Answer (score 1):

```
$vu_data2 = $vu_data->StudentInfo()->get();
```

is returning a collection and not just a single Application Model.  Change "get()" to "first()", and this will fix your first error. So change:

```
$vu_data = Application::where('id', $id)->get();
```

to

```
$vu_data = Application::where('id', $id)->first();
```